# SQL Server 2012 - Intermittant Timeout Issue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am having a darnest time trying to figure out what this is happening...

A very simple query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spListCounties]
@pStateNumeric int
AS

SELECT DISTINCT a.County, a.CountyNumeric
FROM dbo.GeoLocations a
INNER JOIN dbo.Zipcodes b ON b.CityName = a.FeatureName and a.StateAlpha = b.StateAbbr
WHERE a.StateNumeric = @pStateNumeric and a.County<>'' and a.CountyNumeric<>'' and (b.CityType = 'A' OR b.CityType='D')
ORDER by County ASC
```

If I run that query through Analyzer it literally takes less than a second.

Produces
Barnstable  1
Berkshire   3
Bristol 5
Dukes   7
Essex   9
Franklin    11
Hampden 13
Hampshire   15
Middlesex   17
Nantucket   19
Norfolk 21
Plymouth    23
Suffolk 25
Worcester   27

If I run this query through VS2013 with asp.net it literally hangs and times out.

I am not understanding what the heck is the problem.

I have a standard DAL that has been developed to query the database to ensure connections and transactions are closed.

Doing a little more complicated query with a town look up on the same tables it has no problem on the same page.

I have tried rebooting 2012 sql server.  I have restarted it.  I have restarted my IIS (in case it was open connections or application pool issue).  I have closed my visual studio 2013 and reopened it.

And I should say when I left work on friday this was working fine.

All this is on Test sql server and my development machine.

The Test SQL server only has me developing against it and is a Windows 2008 server as a VM running Windows server 2012 operating system.

Anyone have any thoughts about how to figure this out?  Keep in mind I am not a DBA.

Comment: Try setting OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN on the procedure. Could also be a matter of poor statistics.

Comment: Thanks Allan, I been pulling out my hair for about 3.5 hours... trying to figure this out.  redoing indexes, ect....

That worked immediately :)  Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: We are experiencing the same.  Had no issues with SQL Server 2005.  Upgraded to SQL 2012 and today the app could not make connections to the DB for about 20 minutes.  Started working fine on its own after a while.  DB Timeout errors in the app log.